# In Firebase, shall I separate the posts and user data that is updated on a regular basis (favorites, votes...) from the main collection?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a basic app that look like a blog, with posts and users data in Firebase. It is coded in React native, Context API state management and TypeScript.

Users have to possibility to add posts in bookmarks, as well as like the posts.

They also have a partner who's bookmarks are visible from the user and have to be updated in real time. This could be managed by a cloud function or duplicated in a document the partner can access.

The informations needed on posts's lists (homepage) are title, imageUrl, bookmark (for the current user), category.

The informations needed on posts pages is the same, plus totalFavorites, liked, totalLikes, contentText, authorName, authorAvatarURL, authorTitle.

I'm trying to understand the pros and the cons of each of these structures:

**1/ Monolithic**

```
userData:
  - name
  - avatarURL
  - title # for authors
  - bookmarks: 
    - postId: timestamp
    - ...
  - partnerBookmarks: 
    - postId: timestamp
    - ...
  - likes: [postId, ...]

postData:
  - title
  - imageUrl
  - category
  - contentText
  - authorRef: user
  - totalLikes
  - totalFavorites
```

This is pretty straigtforward but there is several concerns:

- I need to be sure that Firestore will not transfert all the userData & postData each time a favorite or a like is added, because this is lots of data that is transfered while it don't change.
- The data need to be separated in React Native context whatsoever to avoid rerendering evrything.

**2/ Fragmented structure**

```
userData: userUid
  - name
  - avatarURL
  - title # for authors


bookmarks: userUid
    - postId: timestamp
    - ...

partnerBookmarks: userUid
    - postId: timestamp
    - ...

likes: userUid
    - postId: true
    - ...

postData: postId
  - title
  - category
  - imageUrl
  - contentText
  - authorRef: user

postDataForLists: postId #Could also be generated by a cloud function to avoid duplicating
  - title
  - imageUrl
  - category

postLikes: postId #Here, separating also enable a rule to prevent authors changing these fields.
  - totalLikes
  - totalFavorites
```

This structure separate concerns, yet since Firestore charge for each read operation so I'm also questionning it.

I'm new to Firebase and I would love to avoid design errors from the start. Please feel free to commment the structure and ask additional questions if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe that this depends a lot on the way your app ends up behaving (and how users actually use your app).

But I believe that fragmented structures save up some reads, but ends up needing some composite indexes for specific interactions that you could end up using in your application. I believe that you could clear this inquiry on the cloud [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) and watching the video content that they have over there, maybe it can help you figuring out the best approach for you.